# Capybara attach_file in remote testing scenario

Tags: selenium, capybara

I'm integration testing with Internet Explorer on a windows machine, running selenium-server, driving the tests from, and hosting the application on, a Mac. The setup works surprisingly well and runs pretty fast.

But when I'm using attach_file to test file upload, Capybara checks that the file exists on the Mac (where Capybara is running), but the attach_file is actually being forwarded to Selenium on another machine, where the browser is running and the file-to-upload resides, and where the file path is totally different. So Capy raises a FileNotFound exception. If I disable this file existence check in Capy, the test passes.

Is this a scenario that was not anticipated in Capybara, or am I doing something really weird? I'll happily make a PR, but not if I'm doing something stupid.

Answer (score 1):

We use the attach_file method in our specs and use a spec/resources/ directory in our repo that keeps a very very small image file. Try to keep the file size as low as possible. As long as the resource file is in the repository, the machine running the selenium test should check out and pull down that file locally.

I am a little surprised that the test passes by disabling the existence check, so I might not fully understand the situation. This solution has helped us run the tests locally and on remote machines though.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to reply, Gabe. Are you saying that the path variable in the attach_file capybara method is actually a url to a computer on the internet?

Comment: the test passes with the existence check disabled b/c 1. the file does not exist on the computer running capybara, and doesn't need to 2. the file needs to be present on the computer in which the browser is running.